# Updating Many-to-Many relationship with LinqToSQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

If I had, for example, a Many-to-Many mapping table called "RolesToUsers" between a Users and an Roles table, here is how I do it:

```
// DataContext is db, usr is a User entity
// newUserRolesMappings is a collection with the desired new mappings, probably 
//   derived by looking at selections in a checkbox list of Roles on a User Edit page
db.RolesToUsers.DeleteAllOnSubmit(usr.RolesToUsers);
usr.RolesToUsers.Clear();
usr.RolesToUsers.AddRange(newUserRolesMappings);
```

I used the SQL profiler once, and this seems to generate very intelligent SQL - it will only drop the rows which are no longer in the mapping relationship, and only add rows which did not already exist in the relationship. It doesn't blindly do a complete clearing and re-construction of the relationship, as I thought it would.

The internet is surprisingly quiet on the subject, and the query "LinqToSQL many-to-many" mostly just turns up articles about how the LinqToSQL data mapper doesn't "support" it very well.

How does everyone else update many-to-many with LinqToSQL?

Comment: Technically, that's not really an ORM equivalent of many-to-many since you are clearing the join table manually.  "Proper" support for m2m in an ORM would model the User object to have a property (or collection) called "Roles", and thus, the ORM would take care of editing the join table under the covers.

Comment: at least that's my interpretation anyway.. HIH

Comment: @RobS: agreed. That also my interpretation: If you just care about one particular user you look at the 'user' objects 'roles' collection. If you care about one particular role, you look at the 'role' objects 'users' collection, respectively. Thats the idea of a ORM, to hide the db stuff, and use it like you were using just objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relation is a set of facts. `Users`, `Roles` and `UsersToRoles` are all relations, and it makes no logical sense to treat one as more "first-class" than another. What you are doing makes perfect sense, which is why is seems to work so nicely.

The ORM world butchers the relational model even worse than SQL does. In particular, it institutionalises the fallacy that relational databases store collections of objects. They don't; they store sets of facts. Many of those facts are *about* entities, which is why the fallacy is so alluring. But plenty of facts are about many other kinds of concepts, such as memberships, events, statuses, opinions, transactions, changes, comparisons, histories, and so on.

Also consider:

1. At some point, you may want to indicate when a user adopted a certain role, and then perhaps whether that role is pending approval, or temporarily revoked. I've found that just about all the "relationships" I want to express in a data model end up carrying a payload in excess of the two foreign keys that make up the many-to-many relationship. If your OR-mapping has been setup to hide the many-to-many (as they tend to do), you'll find the transition to an entity quite painful in terms of code breakages.
2. Often relationships are more complex than binary. "Professor P uses textbook T in class C." may be an irreducible ternary relationship that isn't so easy to hide behind some collection attribute of the Professor object.

   - I just noticed that precisely this issue popped up as a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613347/ternary-and-n-ary-relationships-in-hibernate) a few minutes ago. It appears from the question that JPA 2.0 has had to explicitly add support for ternary relationships (does it handle quaternary, etc., relationships?).

Comment: Of course it works for him, but dont you think you should rather fetch a user object and update its roles collection, and let the ORM do the join table logic? At least he uses a ORM, why shouldnt he benefit from its features?

Comment: You're right about the relationships at the database level, but I disagree when it comes to an abstraction/layer above (or outside) the schema - the UsersToRoles table is kind of useless outside of any context, how likely are you to query just that table by itself?

Comment: @RobS, it is very likely. Firstly, note my two points above. Secondly, UsersToRoles can be queried by itself to build aggregations such as number of users per role, or histogram-type queries such as how many users have more than five roles, or even how many users share more than three roles. This last question is very awkward to answer in a typical ORM.

Comment: @phild, no I don't. As soon as `UsersToRoles` takes on additional attributes (which happens more often than not), the old model breaks and you have to rework a bunch of code. Letting ORMs hide facts in this way leads to pain.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: +1 youre absolutelly right. I have to recall my previous statement... Your two examples are very demonstrative by the way.

Comment: Exactly, and the (Microsoft) Entity Framework will only model a m2m relationship if the join table only has the two referenced keys for either table in a composite PK (and nothing else).  If any additional columns exist it models the relationships as 1:m - m:1

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer to your question, but and explanation why 'the internet is surprisingly quiet on the subject': I guess most people (including me) just update/delete/add *single* items of a n-to-n relationship, and therefore never had to ask themselves the question you have.

Like when you have two tables 'users' and 'roles' and the usecases are just to add/delete a role to/from the user.

Just beeing curious: In which application do you need to update the whole mapping, like your example?

Comment: I have several examples of apps we use, but I'll use this one: 
We have the User, Roles, RolesToUsers setup like in the example of original question. For editing the roles a user is in, there is a list of check boxes on the User Edit page of the admin console. Each checkbox represents a Role. So whatever roles the user was in before, when the admin presses "Submit" editing a user, I get a new list of roles (from the check boxes) that the admin wants the user to be in.

Comment: Now I'm curious. What does that look like in LinqToSQL (assuming this is what you use)? Do you mean to say that you already know the ID of the n-to-n mapping table row you are deleting (when that is the operation)? And that you are always just adding one row to the n-to-n relationship when doing an add?