# Hibernate: Choice object-relational mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this model:

[image]

I can do this representation with hibernate :

[image]

I don`t know which is the better solution, follow this object relational representation, or follow the same representation of the database model (as first image)?

Comment: Why do you think you need Hibernate?  What is it doing for you that can't be done without it?  I'd reconsider that.  The objects and relational models ought to be the same.

Comment: @duffymo is a work on a project that use JPA

Comment: They ought to be the same.  What else makes sense?  If it's a new project, and you have a choice to do it without JPA, I would not use JPA.  Use it if you have a good reason to do so beyond "I have to".

Comment: I found my answer on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613347/ternary-and-n-ary-relationships-in-hibernate

Comment: I think a better answer is: "You don't need Hibernate".  You'll have trouble getting this to work.  You'll be back.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your schema: I think you want a ternary relationship: User-Enterprise-Right.

You end up with three objects:

`User`, `Enterprise`, and `Right`.

The many-to-many relationships mean that there are bi-directional collections involved.

I have no idea if this is a good schema and model, because I don't know your requirements.

```
public class User {
    private List<Enterprise> enterprises;
}

public class Enterprise {
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Your `Right` class isn't clear to me at all.